# Authentication required by wireless network

Tags: wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I'm facing this issue since several weeks now. I have a LenovoT430 with Intel wi-fi card chip. 
I have no clear record of when it started but I'm quite sure that after a while from my clean installation several months ago. However once the system boot-up I keep having pop-ups with this request:

Authentication required by wireless network
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network....

My keypass is already in there and I have double checked many many time. Sometimes also I type is again and again. After a non certain amount of attempts the connection goes up. 
Whenever the laptop goes in sleep or I lock the screen all the nightmare starts again.

I have done 2 different new/fresh installation and during the install all proceed smoothly (when the installation requires a wi-fi connection) but after the start-up the situation still the same. 
On the same machine I have a second disk with W10 and nothing of this is happening. Seems a firmware issue but I have no clue how to proceed further.

Ps. Once the connection is established it remains fixed, except few times that it disconnected.

I'm running Ubuntu LTS and also tried Pop_Os with kernel 5.0.0.23-generic and issue still. 
Only further test that I can have is change the Distro basis to a no Debian one and see what happen.

Thanks

Comment: not a good idea but is it possible for you to create a new SSID and check??

Comment: howww are you logging in, with a password or maybe a fingerprint reader? The password is required to decode the keyring.

Comment: Thanks to both. I'm logging in the laptop with a simple password. No fingerprint reader.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, because of unused network connections **without** credentials.

Check for networks with **similar** names, for example:

Let your network name be MyNetwork, for instance.
Check for network names like 'MyNetwork 1' or 'MyNetwork Home', for example.  Remove those network connections, if you **don't use them**:

Open a Terminal session (Ctrl+Alt+T), and use the following:

```
cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
ls -l *.nmconnection
sudo rm -f 'MyNetwork 1.nmconnection'
```

Then restart the Network Manager:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

or you can use the *Advanced Network Configuration*, from the GUI.